# How to find the distinct values in the array in all the indexes using elasticsearch-dsl?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using elasticsearch-dsl in django. And I have a DocType document defined and a keyword containing a list of values.

Here is my code for the same.

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Text, Keyword

class ProductIndex(DocType):
    """
    Index for products
    """
    id = Keyword()
    slug = Keyword()
    name = Text()
    filter_list = Keyword()
```

filter_list is the array here which contains multiple values. Now I have some values say sample_filter_list which are the distinct values from and some of these elements can be present in some product's filter_list array. So given this sample_filter_list, I want all the unique elements of filter_list of all the products whose filter_list intersection with sample_filter_list in not null.

```
for example I have 5 products whose filter_list is like :
1) ['a', 'b', 'c']
2) ['d', 'e', 'f']
3) ['g', 'h', 'i']
4) ['j', 'k', 'l']
5) ['m', 'n', 'o']
and if my sample filter_list is ['a', 'd', 'g', 'j', 'm']
then elasticsearch should return an array containg distinct element 
i.e. ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            Writing Answer not specific to django but general,
            Suppose you have some ES index some_index2 with mapping

            PUT some_index2
            {
              "mappings": {
                "some_type": {
                  "dynamic_templates": [
                    {
                      "strings": {
                        "mapping": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "match_mapping_type": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "properties": {
                    "field1": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "field2": {
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }

        Also you have inserted the documents 
        {
            "field1":"id1",
            "field2":["a","b","c","d]
        }
        {
            "field1":"id2",
            "field2":["e","f","g"]
        }
        {
            "field1":"id3",
            "field2":["e","l","k"]
        }

    Now as you stated you want all the distinct values of field2(filter_list) in your case, You can easily get that by using ElasticSearch term aggregation

    GET some_index2/_search
    {
    "aggs": {
      "some_name": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "field2",
          "size": 10000
        }
      }
    },
    "size": 0
    }

    Which will give you result as:

    {
      "took": 2,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 3,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "some_name": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "e",
              "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
              "key": "a",
              "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
              "key": "b",
              "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
              "key": "c",
              "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
              "key": "d",
              "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
              "key": "f",
              "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
              "key": "g",
              "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
              "key": "k",
              "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
              "key": "l",
              "doc_count": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }

    where buckets contains the list of all the distinct values.
    you can easily iterate through bucket and find the value under KEY.

Hope this is what is required to you.
```

Comment: I want the all the distinct values of filter_list, only from those document whose, filter_list intersection with sample_filter_list is not null. Please look at the example again.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused about what is it that you want, to just query the products whose `filter_list` intersect with `sample_filter_list` just run a `terms` query:

`ProductIndex.search().filter('terms', filter_list=sample_filter_list)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just want the single array that contains distinct elements from the filter_list of all the products.